# BRST quantization and norm

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, gauge-theory, brst, ghosts

States with definite ghost number have zero norm (since ghost number is anti-hermitian and has real eigenvalues). E.G. when quantizing relativistic point particle, physical spectrum turns out to consist of states with definite ghost number $|k,\uparrow\rangle$, $k^2+m^2=0$. And these states have zero norm.

This isn't very satisfactory, is it? So what do we do? Redefine inner product on BRST cohomology?

UPD: expanding on the question (relativistic particle example). We have a pair of real anticommuting fields $b,c$ with $\{b,c\}=1$. The BRST charge is given by $Q = c (p^2 + m^2)$. An irreducible representation of ghost and antighost is given by $c|\downarrow\rangle=0,\, b|\downarrow\rangle = |\uparrow\rangle,\,c|\uparrow\rangle = |\downarrow\rangle,\,b|\uparrow\rangle=0$.
Physical states obey $Q|\psi\rangle =0$. Up to exact states of the form $Q|a\rangle$ physical spectrum is given by $|k,\uparrow\rangle$ with $k^2+m^2=0$. But $\langle k,\uparrow|k',\uparrow\rangle = \langle k, \downarrow | b b|k',\downarrow\rangle = 0$ for any $k,k'$. This doesn't seem right?

Comment: Why do you think this state belongs to the *physical spectrum*? A physical state has to be BRST-invariant *and* have vanishing ghost number by definition.

Comment: We have real ghost $c$ and antighost $b$. Take ghost number to be $\frac{1}{2}(bc - cb)$. So we have states $|\downarrow\rangle$ with ghost number $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $|\uparrow\rangle$ with $\frac{1}{2}$. BRST charge is $c(p^2 + m^2)$, and physical states (up to exact vectors) are aforementioned.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question why you claim these are the physical states. As I said, zero ghost number is part of what *characterizes a physical state in the first place*.

Comment: Then what states are in this example?

Comment: Well, *if* that is the correct ghost number operator, obviously a state of zero ghost number would be $\lvert \uparrow \rangle + \lvert \downarrow \rangle$, no? You should really define your notation in the question and give reasons why you think a state of non-zero ghost number lies in the physical space of states.

Comment: Well, no, since that state doesn't even have a definite ghost number. Probably more common definition of ghost number would be just $cb$, and the state $|\uparrow\rangle$ will be of zero ghost number.
Why I do think it lies in the physical spectrum is because it is annihilated by $Q$ and is not exact (not equivalent to 0).

Comment: Tip: Consider adding references in order to get useful and focused answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's not very satisfactory.  The usual resolution is to modify the inner product.
$$
\langle\langle A | B \rangle \rangle \equiv \langle A | c | B \rangle
$$
Then inserting $\{ b, c \} = 1$ into the norm no longer yields a vanishing result.  Alternatively, as the questioner did, one can try to use the facts that $|{\uparrow} \rangle = b | {\downarrow} \rangle$ and $b^2 = 0$, but now we will find $bcb$ inside the old inner product instead.

The modified inner product has additional benefits.  With respect to the new norm, the ghost current becomes Hermitian.

The state $|k, \uparrow \rangle$ does indeed have nonzero ghost number, as the questioner asserts. Perhaps the comments were about the no ghost theorem.  The no ghost theorem, however, is a statement that physical states must not have negative norm, not that they have zero ghost number.

Comment: Physical states in the BRST formalism are usually *defined* to be the BRST-invariant states with zero ghost number, at least the way I learned it, cf. chapter 14 in *"Quantization of Gauge Systems"* by Henneaux and Teitelboim. Extending the formalism to have states of non-zero ghost number in the physical spectrum is non-standard. As an example, consider that the restriction of physical string states to those of conformal weight 1 is precisely that to those of zero ghost number.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this textbook.  My source is unpublished lecture notes from Peter van Nieuwenhuizen.  But think what I'm saying is actually familiar from the bc system in string theory, where it's natural, on the torus to set $\langle \uparrow | \downarrow \rangle = 1$ instead of $\langle \downarrow | \downarrow \rangle = 1$.  These $|\uparrow \rangle$ and $| \downarrow \rangle$ states are then related to the $SL_2(R)$ invariant vacuum by further acting with the $c$ ghost, leading to say (1.52) in http://hep.itp.tuwien.ac.at/~kreuzer/inc/sst2.pdf.